# How to insert multiple documents into Meteor collection via connection API?

Tags: meteor

I want to use [xcv58:collection-api](https://atmospherejs.com/xcv58/collection-api) Meteor package (which is a fork of 
[mrt:collection-api](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/collection-api)) to access MongoDB data. But its brief documentation doesn't cover multiple document insertion and I can't find an example of that. Is it possible and if not is there proper alternative?

Comment: I haven't tried, but mongodb let you insert multiple document when insert an array. Have you tried `$ curl -H "X-Auth-Token: 97f0ad9e24ca5e0408a269748d7fe0a0" -d "[{\"name\": \"John Smith\"},{˜\"name\":\"John Doe\"}"` (from examples, extended)? I'm curious now! :)

Comment: @CFrei, that is the first obvious thing to try and sure I tried it. It is inserted as a single object, like this `{ "_id" : "hdMXsdZnNJ3YbQAts", "0" : { "name" : "John Smith" }, "1" : { "name" : "John Doe" }}`